# "_ssgManifest.js" & _buildManifest.js missing from a nextjs app hosted on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, gcloud

sometimes the console shows these errors on opening the website

```
GET https://example.com/subpath/_next/static/9ufj5kFJf/_buildManifest.js
[HTTP/3 404 Not Found 311ms]

GET https://example.com/subpath/_next/static/9ufj5kFJf/_ssgManifest.js
[HTTP/3 404 Not Found 334ms]

Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://example.com/subpath/_next/static/9ufj5kFJf/_buildManifest.js”. 1434-247:1:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://example.com/subpath/_next/static/9ufj5kFJf/_ssgManifest.js”.
```

the app does use ISR and that seems to be working, it does get updated, what do these files do? what could happen if they are missing?

- "react": "17.0.2"
- "next": "10.1.3",
- "node" "15.1.2"

Comment: I think [this github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18389) may help you. Also you have mentioned that you have hosted the application on gcloud. Can you please add more details like which infrastructure in Google Cloud Platform (Google App Engine/ Google Kubernetes Engine/ Google Compute Engine or anything else) you are using  to host the Next.js application and any specific documentation you are following?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with GCP (Kubernetes engine) with pods count > 1. I resolved the issue by restarting the deployment (all pods).

Answer (score 0):

On [that Github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18389) @Prabir linked to in a comment, [someone posted](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18389#issuecomment-719581958) a way to use the generateBuildId function within the Next.js config file:

```
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;

const lastCommitCommand = "git rev-parse HEAD";

module.exports = {
  async generateBuildId() {
    return execSync(lastCommitCommand).toString().trim();
  },
};
```

I work with an app that uses some combination of AWS CodeBuild and Docker images, which prevents direct access to all the git commands so that snippet above didn't work. But using `CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID` or really any environment variable (unique to either that commit or the build itself) did. I'm not as familiar with the GCP-equivalents but [this Cloud Build Docs page](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_default_substitutions) makes it seem like `$COMMIT_SHA` would be a good option to try.

Answer (score 0):

Mine might be nieche but I am posting it in case it will help someone since I've been pulling hair over it (and I am bald).

I had a file called middleware.ts that had the following code:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

// Convert all paths to lower case
const Middleware = (req: any) => {
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === req.nextUrl.pathname.toLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next();

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(req.nextUrl.origin + req.nextUrl.pathname.toLowerCase()));
};

export default Middleware;
```

once I removed it the problem got fixed.